# mcautocomplete disappearing over slickgrid

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, slickgrid

I added mcautocomplete to my slickgrid. if I check some of the checkboxes mcautocomplete table is not visible anymore on slickgrid. Please check the pic.
How do i make sure that my autocomplete options are visible over my slickgrid?

[image]

```
     $.widget('custom.mcautocomplete', $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function () {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu("option", "items", "> :not(.ui-widget-header)");
    },
    _renderMenu: function (ul, items) {
        var self = this,
            thead;
        if (this.options.showHeader) {
            table = $('<div class="ui-widget-header" style="width:100%"></div>');
            $.each(this.options.columns, function (index, item) {
                table.append('<span style="font-weight:bold;background-color:#EEE8AA;padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + item.width + ';">' + item.name + '</span>');
            });
            table.append('<div style="clear: both;"></div>');
            ul.append(table);
        }
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            self._renderItem(ul, item);
        });
    },
    _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
        var t = '',
            result = '';
        $.each(this.options.columns, function (index, column) {
            t += '<span style="background-color:#ADD8E6;padding:0 4px;float:left;width:' + column.width + ';">' + item[column.valueField ? column.valueField : index] + '</span>'
        });
        result = $('<div></div>')
            .data('ui-autocomplete-item', item)
            .append('<div class="mcacAnchor">' + t + '<div style="clear: both;"></div></div>')
            .appendTo(ul);
        return result;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try z-index (this can be complex and all comes down to the priority of the container elements), but I have found that the structure of some javascript controls are simply not compatible with SlickGrid.
(not saying that mcautocomplete is not compatible, with the right tweaks, but it MAY not be).

For example, I was using 'chosen' for dropdowns, but as it used table elements that would not play well with the slickgrid infrastructure, I had to abandon that for 'select2'.  There is a 'select2' example in the 6pac github repository, and I think select2 has an autocorrect mode. Might be worth a try.

Comment: I found the example and it works great. thank you very much. http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-select2-editor.html